# ThreadPool don't run submitted tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have strange problem with java ThreadPool

I'm define executorService as follow:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
```

and later submit tasks:

```
while (!manager.stop()) {
   File file = getFile();
   if (file != null) {
       String name = file.getName();
       log.debug("add new task with name {}", name);
       outExecutorInfo();
       Future<?> task = executorService.submit(getTask(file));
       outTaskInfo(task);
       executeTasks.put(name, task);
       outExecuteTasks();
   }
}
```

outExecuteTasks log some debug info including task count:

```
log.debug("activeCount={}, completedTaskCount={}, taskCount={}. poolSize={}", 
     new Object[] { activeCount, completedTaskCount,taskCount, poolSize });
```

after running some time (after exected 50-100 task according to thread pool completedTask counter) i'm see strange behavior - submitted tasks appends to pool queue but not executed at all! ThreadPool reported active tasks = 0, task queue size big and counting, and none of tasks executed according to log.
Has someone some problem?

Comment: Could be a bug in Java. Are you using the latest version of JRE available?

Comment: Hmmm... not sure. I'm use latest JRE in develop and test enviroment, but not sure about production... I'll check it.

Comment: I think possibility of JDK bug is very small. you code should be checked again.

Comment: this server has about 40 installation and problem only in two of them. I'm check software versions of worked and not worked instances and only diff is Linux kernel version. I'll try to reinstall linux to isolate this. Also there used java 1.6_01 and may be i'm need to upgrade it too.

Comment: Use log statements in getTask(file) to check whether your tasks are getting executed or not. getTask(file) in your case should return a Runnable in which run method will be overridden. place some trace statements in the run method and check it

Comment: @Rustum already done. I'm put log at first line in run() method of my task (returned by getTask), and as i'm say - even first line now shown in my log file, so i'm decide task even not executed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i'm collect enough statistics to say: this is problem of concrete linux kernel

```
[root@mag]$ uname -a
Linux ns.mag 2.4.20-8smp #1 SMP Thu Mar 13 17:45:54 EST 2003 i686 i686 i386  GNU/Linux
```

of redhat box. This not reproduced even on 2.4.31 and hihger.